# Many to many database association in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord, associations

I am creating a sort of card collection programme with codeigniter and ion_auth for authentication. A user should be able to add a card to his collection. 
So i have a users table and a cards table and a junction/bridge table.

```
    users
    ID
    NAME
```

and

```
    cards
    ID
    NAME
```

and

```
    users_cards
    ID
    USER_ID
    CARD_ID
```

I want to accomplish a SELECT statement that retrieves the cards from a users through user_cards.

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('cards');
$this->db->join('users_cards', 'users.id = users_cards.user_id', 'inner');
$this->db->join('users', 'users_cards.user_id = users.id', 'inner');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();
```

I cant seem to get a grasp at the concept of these joins. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the join statement is missing the reference to the 'cards' table.

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('users_cards');
$this->db->join('users', 'users.id = users_cards.user_id', 'inner');
$this->db->join('cards', 'cards.id = users_cards.card_id', 'inner');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();
```

The idea is that you're trying to get a relationship going between users_cards and the other two tables by referencing their relevant ids

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't joined users table you can't join based on the users.id reference. So you need to change

```
$this->db->join('users_cards', 'users.id = users_cards.user_id', 'inner');
```

to

```
$this->db->join('users_cards', 'cards.id = users_cards.card_id', 'inner');
```